# Opening a html page with ShadowBox

Tags: javascript, html, shadowbox

I am trying to open a html page in shadowbox onload.

```
function AlertMessage(){
    Shadowbox.open({
          player:     'html', 
        content:    'http://www.google.com',
        height:     350,
        width:      470
    });
}



Shadowbox.init({

      players:  [ 'html'] 
});

 <body onload="AlertMessage();">
```

It doesn't show up anything. I can put HTML content in the shadowbox, however I am not sure how to put a url in there. e.g. I want to open google.com in the shadowbox. How do it it?
This has been discussed previously, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

Comment: Try adding timer to the alert message function. Like 1 second.

Comment: I am not sure why we need a timer

Comment: Do you have script tags in your real code ? :)

Comment: yes, off course. It works for html content. I am not able to specify a url. If I specify as above,it treats the url as a part of html